# Do I need to do anything at the frontend to do anything to use TLS express api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ssl, axios

I am quite new to the web and I am currently running into an issue. I want to build a safe express API but I am stuck and couldn't find much about this (I believe I don't know the right keyword to search for related articles).

So here's the problem. I am using a react frontend and an express backend. I want to use TLS to secure my APIs. So, I first generate the cert with OpenSSL and config the backend as follows:

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import { createServer as createHttpsServer } from 'https'
import express from 'express'
import helmet from 'helmet'

const app = express();
app.use(helmet())

// configure TLS server
const server = createHttpsServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync(config.ssl_key).toString(),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(config.ssl_cert).toString(),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(config.ssl_ca).toString(),
    }, app
);

// Listen to port
server.listen(config.port, config.host, () => {
            console.log(`HTTPS server is now listening on ${config.host}:${config.port}!`));
```

After setting up the backend, I am wondering what should I do at the frontend to use the TLS. Do I need to sign the certificate at the react frontend before using Axios to connect to the backend? Or can I directly use Axios at the frontend without the need of signing any kind of cert or registering for anything?

Thank you, I really appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify the [`requestCert`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/tls.html#tlscreateserveroptions-secureconnectionlistener) option to your server, it will not request a certificate from the client (and the [`ca`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/tls.html#tlscreatesecurecontextoptions) option has no effect). Therefore the client (that is, your browser) does not need a client certificate.

However, it must trust the *server* certificate from your [`cert`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/tls.html#tlscreatesecurecontextoptions) option. Unless you had your server certificate signed by a trusted root certification authority (and paid for that), your browser will refuse the connection unless you upload the server certificate (or the root certificate that signed it) as a "trusted certificate".